# python import system variable path to working script to work with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, path

i have a python script that i wanna launch the help file from anywhere on my machine or others machine.
So i try to import the 'TEST' folder as the working folder for the script.
Test folder is allready set as its own in varible settings in windows

```
import os
chubba = os.environ['Test'] 
subprocess.Popen("chubba", "helper.chm", shell = True)
```

nothing happends when runned

also i have tried having the helper.chm and the script in same folder.

```
import os
import sys
sys.append.path([0])
subprocess.Popen("helper.chm", shell = True)
```

dosent work either

any idea

Comment: I don't understand your directory structure, what's chubba? is it a directory in %TEST% that holds helper.chm?

Comment: the os.environ['Test'] is a varible name https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500, so basicly 'TEST' is a folder, i trying to run a script anywhere from the pc, and yes 'TEST' have the helper.vhm file. I know that i can do sys.append.path('/TEST')

Comment: os.environ['Test'] holds the string 'chubba'? And that's a path to a directory holding 'helper.chm'? If so, things won't work well because its not an absolute path name. All you really need is the full path to the .chm, but that means you need to know the rules for how you've setup your directory. eg, is 'chubba' based on the users home directory?

Comment: im trying to make 'chubba' act like the 'TEST' folder in the subprocess.Popen(), the test folder have the helper.chm.I wanna share the script with others so i thought it would be easyer to have them Create a Environmental Variable Windows, insteed of having them editing the script,since they could have the helper.chm in any folder.or different strycture than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows, help can be displayed simply by running the .chm file. The trick is that you need to tell Popen where the .chm file is. You don't specify the location, but suppose the rule is that the .chm file is in a directory named by %Test% under the user's home directory. Then you'd do:

```
import subprocess
import os
p = Popen(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), os.path.expandvars('%Test%'),
    'helper.chm'), shell=True)
```

Comment: nothing happends i have the helper.chm in c:\TEST and have that in the Environmental Variable Windows not in the "PATH", then my script in c:\script.py, is there a way, if i move my script to c:\TEST to add the working dir to Popen insteed, without setting ,  sys.append.path('path/to/dir) . Also dont understand he p =.The subprocess.Popen execute the helper.chm direct